# Error in g.cs file with ListViewItem ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ListView` with a context menu for each item defined:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ListViewForeground}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Edit" Click="editContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding enable_Disable_OppositeText}" Click="enable_disable_ContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="deleteContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <EventSetter Event="Control.MouseDoubleClick" Handler="discreteListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

And the `Click` handlers behind:

```
private void editContextMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Edit");
}

private void enable_disable_ContextMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enable/Disable");
}

private void deleteContextMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Delete");
}
```

Currently, this shows errors in the .g.cs file when built/ran:

1. } Expected
2. { Expected
3. Invalid expression term '}'
4. ; expected

If the 3 `Menu Item` lines are removed, it builds successfully.  Cleaning the solution and rebuilding hasn't worked; neither has deleting the `bin` and `obj` directories and rebuilding.  Also, the namespace and class names have not been changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue.  In my project the `EventSetter.Handler` is underlined (VS 2015) with the error:

> Invalid value for property 'Handler': 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Semantics.XmlValue

There are some remarks in [`EventSetter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventsetter(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation but I didn't take the time to read them.  I came up with a working solution as see below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ListView>
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="Control.MouseDoubleClick" Handler="discreteListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ListViewForeground}"/>
               <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
               <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <ContextMenu>
                           <MenuItem Header="Edit" Click="editContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                           <MenuItem Header="{Binding enable_Disable_OppositeText}" Click="enable_disable_ContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                           <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="deleteContextMenuItem_Click"/>
                       </ContextMenu>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the only change is moving the double-click event handler outside of the ListView.  By doing this, won't every ListViewItem be handled by this single method?  Is there any way to differentiate between senders?

Comment: You need to cast your `sender` some way in the event handler and use that to differentiate between them.  It looks like you're attempting to use MVVM and I'm glad you are; but typically you'd be assigning a `DataTemplate` that contains a control with a `ContextMenu`, to the `ListView.ItemTemplate`.  Then you would bind the `MenuItem.Command` to an `ICommand` that exists in the type that is bound to the item.  I move the Style to `ListView.Resources` so that it only applies to that specific `ListView` and not all the `ListView`s in the application.

Comment: Feel free to ask questions in [WPF chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf).

Comment: I ended up figuring it out--since I had two different listboxes (that were different enough to warrant separate functionality) I just created separate ContextMenus and put them in their respective ListView.Resource.  Then I was able to put the EventSetter back into each ListView.  Thanks for your help!